# Magnetic field and relationship with charged particles

Tags: magnetic-fields, charge

I would like to know what would happen if a neutral particle is inside a uniform magnetic field. Would it be moving? What would happen to the force?

Comment: It could affect the magnetic moment orientation of the neutral particle but would have no noticeable affect on the particle's motion (unless we are talking about pair-production strength fields).

Answer (score 1):

That will depend on the fact if the particle has a magnetic moment or not. Generally, it will not change the trajectory of the particle but it will reorient its magnetic moment. Though the orientation will not be very strict - the particle magnetic moment will precess around the vector of the field with a certain frequency. This is called Larmor precession and the corresponding frequency is a Larmor frequency. There is a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_precession) page which can introduce you to this phenomenon.

EDIT:
Just to clarify - since other answers seem to mainly focus on charged particles - the trajectory of the particle in a uniform magnetic field will change due to Lorentz force only for charged particles. In case of a neutral particle with a non-zero magnetic moment in a uniform field you will only see the Larmor precession. However, in case of a magnetic particle in a non-uniform field there will be an additional force acting on the particle in the direction of the gradient of the field.

Answer (score 0):

In a uniform magnetic field, the magnitude of force on the particle is $$qvB \sin\theta$$

where, $v$ is the velocity of charged particle, $B$ is the magnetic field, $q$ is the charge on the particle, and $\theta$ is the angle between the particle's velocity vector and magnetic field vector.

As you have specifically asked about neutral particles, $q=0$, so the force acting on them is zero.

Comment: By the way, in English, only capitalize [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) and the first word of each sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Any particle will experience a force if the Lorentz force formula yields a non-zero value. The Lorentz force formula is given by:
$$\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times\vec{B})$$

1. Only charged particles can experience a force in the magnetic field
2. Only moving charged particles can experience a force in the magnetic field
3. There must be a non-zero component of the velocity (or magnetic field) along the magnetic field (or velocity).